# WordPress Front end editor

Tags: front-end, editor

According to this https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/a-look-at-the-upcoming-wordpress-front-end-editor

this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-front-end-editor/ is going to be in a future release of WordPress.

As of WordPress 4.0.7 I don't see this front end editor. So I'd expect a gazillion downloads of this new editor but I only see 3000 active installs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: [that plugin is currently listed as inactive](https://make.wordpress.org/core/features-as-plugins/), doesn't look like there's been any movement on it for months.

Comment: Exactly - is this plugin now in WP core? If so, where?